# Can I get the documentation of the built-in "sum" function of Python 2.7 in a Linux Terminal?

Tags: python, linux

When I search the Python documentation website, I can get the ["sum" function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum), but when I search the Help on built-in Python module in the Linux terminal, I don't find this topic. Can I get the documentation of the built-in "sum" function of Python in a Linux Terminal?

Answer (score 3):

In a python console you enter:

```
>>> help(sum)
```

In `ipython` you can use:

```
 In [1]: sum??
```

In general you can have access to documentation string like this:

```
sum.__doc__
```

Comment: Okay. Now if I have x = [1, 3, 4] and then I do dir(x), why the "sum" function is not listed?

Comment: `sum` is not a method of list, it's just a function that can take parameter that is a list. In few words, it's a global method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
$ pydoc sum
```

if you are looking for a "man" page from the normal bash shell

from the python interpretter as mentioned you can do

```
>>> help(sum)
```

and from ipython you can do

```
in [1]: sum?
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `help(sum)` in python?

Answer (score 0):

Use the help function:

```
>>> help(sum)
```